# WD "Green" HD causes few-seconds lockups after wake from sleep - how to disable auto-shutdown?

Tags: hard-drive

My desktop has a non-OS drive D: 2000MB WD Green (model WD20EARS-00MVWB0, firmware version 51.0AB51).

After the computer boots / wakes from sleep, in the first time I access D: drive, the program which accesses it (Explorer / etc.) locks up for several seconds. If the computer wakes up and there was some program accessing the drive (say, an Explorer window open), then the log-on screen will lockup for several seconds.

I presume the drive's firmware deliberately spins-up only on access, and I want to disable this behavior. I've found [an Anandtech post](http://forums.anandtech.com/showthread.php?t=2126870) that mentions [WD's WDIDLE3.exe utility](http://support.wdc.com/product/download.asp?groupid=609&sid=113). However, this utility lists several 750-1000MB drive, with a stern warning not to use on any other drives. There's also [idle3-tools](http://idle3-tools.sourceforge.net/), but that's only for Linux.

How can I disable this behavior through Windows?

OS: Windows 8 64-bit, though it happened with Windows XP as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read through this [WD forum thread](http://community.wdc.com/t5/Desktop-Portable-Drives/Green-Caviar-High-Load-Cycle-Cout-after-short-operation-time/td-p/15731) and this [WD Knowledge Base article](http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5357) carefully. The **WD20EARS** Green drive ***is*** supported by the WDIdle3 utility. I have used it myself from an [MS-DOS/FreeDOS USB stick](http://www.synology.com/support/faq_show.php?lang=enu&q_id=407) to change the idle timer, and I believe `WDIDLE3 /D` should disable the timer completely (or at least set it to its max supported value; check `WDIDLE3 /?` for all supported options).

Note: Although the operation should be safe (I ran it on a drive that was almost full), it's always a good idea to have a backup of your data before attempting something like this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that after I setup a backup (at least of irreplaceable material).

Answer (score 1):

IIRC the "green" range can't have these features tweaked any more, thought the "black" (and perhaps also the "blue") ranges do - they are pretty much locked to the low-power settings.

Though this is 2nd-hand information as I bought different drives instead having found people discussing similar issues.

Comment: I can confirm that your second-hand info. is incorrect.

Comment: Fair enough. At the time I was looking I got the impression that *some* Green drives supported the switching of those options bits (along with others like "RAID-quick-fail") but most didn't and you could not guarantee which revision of the units you were getting. +1 for providing a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when backup my Linux servers to WD green USB drives. Simple way to do this is to ping the drive every minute or so. In Linux I do this via crontab, in windows you can do this by creating a little bat script and running it in Scheduled Tasks.

## SpinDrive.bat

D:
dir

#

Create a scheduled tax to run this every minute or so.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I'm more interested in the post boot/wake-up behavior, for which a scheduled task will no help much.

Comment: You could hook something to the wake-up phase that read something relatively random (to reduce the chance of it being in cache) from the drive (or wrote a small temporary file to the drive and forced a flush-to-disk). I know the Linux power management tools in most distros allow this relatively easily so I assume Windows has a way too. That would spin up the drive as fast as anything could after a wake from sleep or hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I use [QuietHDD](https://sites.google.com/site/quiethdd/). Set APM to 255 and AAM to 254 (these are max settings). It will hopefully ensure that your drive won't spin down.