# How to stop auto turn off hard disk spining, in windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive

My secondary hard disk (internal SATA drive) which is an hard disk (not SSD) it stops spinning automatically after about a minute ... (a sound is heard from it as when I turned off)

I want to stop this feature in windows 10 !

Every time when I access a file from it, it takes about 1-2 seconds to start (a sound is heard that starts rotating the discs)

It is very annoying because sometimes it blocks cursive application functionality...

Even if I set to 0 "Turn off Hard disk" in "Power option", nothing happens..., also I tried to set at 60 minutes or something, but the result is same, hard disk stop running after about one minute...

I want the hard drive to run continuously, without stopping!

Thanks in advance!

Silviu

Comment: Try [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1013569/8672).

Comment: You can use KepAliveHD, https://github.com/stsrki/keepalivehd or similar apps, but some external HDD are not designed to run *continuously*. So use the program only when you're using that HDD often.

Comment: Are we talking about an internal SATA drive or an external USB drive? If it is the latter the energy saving mechanism is often built-in in the USB enclosure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent a secondary HDD from spinning down?](https://superuser.com/questions/1013553/how-to-prevent-a-secondary-hdd-from-spinning-down)