# Do drive spin-down times have to be set individually?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, troubleshooting

In Windows, do hard drive spin-down times have to be set individually, per drive?

I set the drive spin down time to 180 minutes through Power Options, as I'm tired of having to wait for drives to spin up when I need them (I had it set at 20 minutes).

However, after applying the new 180 minute option and many reboots later, I still have to wait for drives when accessing them through Explorer. It's like the new spin-down time setting didn't apply.

Is this a per-drive setting? Does it only work with the main OS drive (C:)?

My main OS drive (C:) is an Intel SSD. Then I have four mechanical storage drives. I've wondered if perhaps there's some other function that's getting in the way of accessing the drives "cold", giving the appearance of spun-down drives, like Windows initiating some type of network scan for network drives before listing local directories...?

Comment: Both the OS (in your case windows-7) **and** the drives can initiate a sleep mode where the drive spins down.

Adjusting the "power options" in windows *probably* only configured the OS part. You still need to set that on the drives.

(As to how to do that from windows: No idea. For BSD/Linux/OSX I would use hdparms).

Comment: Additionally the drive manufacturer might provide a low level utility to do this, [as is the case](http://superuser.com/a/529612/138343) for certain WD "Green" drives.