# HDD shuts down when writing files

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive

Every time I'm writing big files (or a lot of small ones) to my HDD it shuts down after some time (10-20 minutes) (happens when downloading big torrents or unpacking big files). A popup then shows that I didn't remove my HDD properly..

It's then not visible anymore in Finder or Disk Utility (even in Recovery Mode). I have to open my macbook and unplug my hdd and plug it back in again to make it visible in Finder again.

It's a second harddisk I placed in my Macbook Pro.

I can't say for sure if it only happens when writing files.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem.  I would replace the hdd in question.

Comment: It might also be overheating.

Comment: If you're happening to be using a WD Green disk, read the stuff at https://superuser.com/questions/529436/wd-green-hd-causes-few-seconds-lockups-after-wake-from-sleep-how-to-disable regarding the power-saving sleep function utilized by the disk that, when malfunctioning, can cause premature shutdown of the disk. Unlikely that you have a WD Green (you're on a MacBook Pro), but do consider all cases.